# CPLEX equivalent C++ of cplexmiqp MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, cplex

I have a matlab script, which uses Cplex, to implement in C++. Does the C++ equivalent of the toolbox function **cplexmiqp** exist ? 
If not, how can I solve my problem? I only have the parameters needed to this function to solve the MIP problem (H, f, Aineq, bineq, Aeq, beq, sostype, sosind, soswt, lb, ub, ctype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cplexmiqp](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refmatlabcplex/html/cplexmiqp-m.html) is a convenience function in the CPLEX [MATLAB Toolbox API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/MATLAB/topics/gs_ov_toolbox.html). There is nothing exactly equivalent to this in the [C++ API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/APIs/Cpp/cpp_synopsis.html). However, the C++ API is actually more powerful/flexible and you can definitely accomplish the same task. You'll have to build the model using your input data, solve it, and query the solution using methods in the C++ API. I'd suggest that you take a close look at the **ilomiqpex1.cpp** example that is shipped with CPLEX.